# Magento: How to show unset attributes as empty not "No" / "N/A"?

Tags: magento

Magento has done great job on showing empty attributes as "No" or "N/A", but
I need them to show up as empty table cells.

I know this code hides empty attributes completely:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Source: http://www.magthemes.com/magento-blog/empty-attributes-showing-na-fix/

but as I am new to php, I don't really know how to modify it to show them empty.

I know I could go to core files and modify Attributes.php, but thats a bad practice and I wanted to do it right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can write a extension thar rewrites Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes::getAdditionalData. But this requires much more knowledge than is necessary to modify the template.
2. Modify template. Your code is already done. Only few modifications need

   ```
   <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
   <?php 
       $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
       $_isEmpty = (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) &&((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != ''));
   ?>

       <tr>
           <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
           <td class="data"><?php if (!$_isEmpty) { echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])} ?> </td>
       </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```

P.S. Code can contain errors, have not tested :)

Comment: almost perfect. just 2 things in if:
<?php if ($_isEmpty) { echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);} ?>

works for me ;) thanks

Comment: Does not work with ce-1.9.0.1 try something like `$_isEmpty = !$_product->getData($_data['code'])`

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+0160

Use the above keyboard shortcut as the attribute value when you edit your product.

How?

On Windows, at least, do the following:

Hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and type the numbers 0160 on your keypad. Now release the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key.

Basically a whitespace character appears that is not a space character. This will register as a non-null value for your product field and the engine will render the character which, fortunately for us humans, is a whitespace that we won't see.

It's not elegant, but it will help those who aren't able to modify template code.

Answer (score 1):

i try with this options to remove "No or N/A" and ok remove this words but don´t remove atribute name. i use this code:

```
 <?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="akordeon-item-head">
    <div class="akordeon-item-head-container">
        <div class="akordeon-heading">
            <?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="akordeon-item-body">
    <div class="akordeon-item-content">
        <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <?php 
    $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    $_isEmpty = (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) &&((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != ''));?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php if ($_isEmpty) { echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);} ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i find this anwerd and work for me

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
<?php if ($_data['value'] == 'No') {continue;} ?>
<tr>
    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
</tr>
```